# How to convert Color Literal to cgColor in the Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicolor, cgcolor

`var CodeBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1294117647, green: 0.1294117647, blue: 0.1960784314, alpha: 1)`

`cells?.layer.borderColor = //... how can i set this color literal to cgColor?`

As I know how to convert that UIColor to cgColor in the Swift

as example

`UIColor.black.cgColor`

Bingo, but what about Color Literal to cgColor in the Swift

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly the same thing `whatever.cgColor`. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxd6nw06z1adxzq/color%20literal.jpg?dl=1  BTW it is Swift naming convention to name your objects starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: That's still problems, I running to iOS Simulator and refused to show up the color. (unless if you create more than one cells could effect bugs when you slide down to pass that one cell and slide up and it was same from different cells). I just need to set UIColor, however that code show error that requests to use cgColor from UIColor....seem weird.

Comment: cells are reusable

Comment: Table view has a method called `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` You can clear the cell content as soon as the table view ends displaying it

Comment: thing simply easy, use like: viewBack.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1).cgColor//UIColor.white

Comment: Mmm, sound interesting. Let me try that method. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As, You already know the simpler way of using `colorLiteral` as `cgcolor`, I'll jump to the other way of doing that...
- For that you need a Custom Function which gets the color-value(red , green , blue) from the `colorLiteral` , which is as below

  ```
  extension UIColor {
      func rgb() -> (red:Int, green:Int, blue:Int, alpha:Int)? {
      var fRed : CGFloat = 0
      var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
      var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
      var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
      if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
          let iRed = Int(fRed * 255.0)
          let iGreen = Int(fGreen * 255.0)
          let iBlue = Int(fBlue * 255.0)
          let iAlpha = Int(fAlpha)

          _ = (iAlpha << 24) + (iRed << 16) + (iGreen << 8) + iBlue
          return (red:iRed, green:iGreen, blue:iBlue, alpha:iAlpha)
      } else {
          // Could not extract RGBA components:
          return nil
      }
  }
  }
  //It's more convenient to use function in `UIColor` extension
  ```
- Now , after this function created you can convert `colorliteral` into `cgColor` as below...

  ```
  let CodeBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1294117647, green: 0.1294117647, blue: 0.1960784314, alpha: 1)
  let rgblit = CodeBackground.rgb()
  let Converted_cgColor = CGColor(srgbRed: CGFloat(integerLiteral: rgblit!.red), green: CGFloat(integerLiteral: rgblit!.green), blue: CGFloat(integerLiteral: rgblit!.blue), alpha: CGFloat(integerLiteral: rgblit!.alpha))
  ```
- You can directly use `Converted_cgColor` like

  ```
  cells?.layer.borderColor = Converted_cgColor
  ```

***HOPE IT HELPS***

Comment: Ahh, That's worked! however, this code effected the whole of the cells went invisible like nothing to show the color while I followed your course.

Comment: Kindly Upvote it to support & Approve the answer if it worked :)

Comment: Now, I found out there is ways to add code the border color in one cell, except all cells don't need it seems worked as well. I upvoted and approved it. :)